# Show $W^{1,q}_0(-1,1)\subset C([-1,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I need show that space $W^{1,q}_0(-1,1)$ is a subset of $C([-1,1])$ space. How I will able to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q=+\infty$, and $\varphi_n$ are test functions such that $\lVert \varphi_n-u\rVert_{\infty}\to 0$, then we can find a set of measure $0$ such that $\sup_{x\in  [-1,1]\setminus N}|\varphi_n(x)-u(x)|\to 0$, so $u$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function, and can be represented by it.

We assume $1\leqslant q<\infty$.
As $W_0^{1,q}(-1,1)$ consists of equivalence classes of functions and $C[-1,1]$ consists of functions, what we have to show is that each element of $W_0^{1,q}(-1,1)$ can be represented by a continuous function. First, for $\varphi$ a test function, we have 
$$|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|\leqslant \left|\int_x^y|\varphi'(x)|dx\right|\leqslant |x-y|^{1-1/q}\lVert\varphi'\rVert_{L^q}.$$
Now, let $u\in W_0^{1,q}(-1,1)$. By definition, we can find a sequence $\{\varphi_k\}\subset D(-1,1)$ such that $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\lVert u-\varphi_k\rVert_q+\lVert u'-\varphi'_k\rVert_q=0.$
Up to a subsequence, we can assume that $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\varphi_k(x)=u(x)$. As for  $k$ large enough, 
$$|\varphi_k(x)-\varphi_k(y)|\leqslant |x-y|^{1-1/q}(\lVert u'\rVert_{L^q}+1),$$
we have for almost every $x, y\in (-1,1)$,
 $$|u(x)-u(y)|\leqslant |x-y|^{1-1/q}(\lVert u'\rVert_{L^q}+1),$$
what we wanted (and even more, as $u$ is represented by a $\left(1-\frac 1q\right)$-Hölder continuous function, as noted robjohn).

Comment: So not only are they continuous, but they are also Hölder $1-1/q$ continuous. (+1)

Comment: Yes, actually we have a more accurate inclusion.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Why this $\lVert \varphi_n-u\rVert_{\infty}\to 0$. For any function $u$ is this true?

Comment: I meant, for $u\in W^{1,\infty}$, hence in particular in $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo where I will be able to find your affirmation?

Comment: Which one? {}{}{}

Comment: @DavideGiraudo For all $u$ always exist a $\phi_n$  sucht that $\lVert \varphi_n-u\rVert_{\infty}\to 0$

Comment: It's true for $u\in W^{1,\infty}_0$ by definition (as the closure of test functions for $||v||:=||v||_{\infty}+||v'||_{\infty}$.